# Проблема с кодировкой в графиках matplotlib

Tags: python, кодировка, matplotlib

При создании графика в matplotlib возникает проблема с тем, что подписи на русском языке отображаются некорректно:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.xlabel('текст')
```

[image: График]

Comment: Шрифт, по-умочанию используемый в matplotlib, не содержит русских букв. Нужно его сменить, например, как советует в своем ответе Тимофей.

Comment: День добрый. Ну, мне это не помогло. И Sans тоже не помог. Как определить, что писать в "семействе"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как решение можно использовать следующий код:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('font', family='Verdana')
```

Если после этого попробовать отобразить график, то текст будет отображён правильно.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.xlabel('текст')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]